# Status for threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am using a multi thread concept in my application.I am using below code

```
 Dim threadHistory As Thread = Nothing
                For Each dRow As DataRow In sqlDS.Tables(0).Rows
                    GetPropertyBidHistory(dRow("ID"))
                    threadHistory = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetRowHistory)
                    threadHistory.Name = "Row" + dRow("ID")    
                    threadHistory.Start(dRow("ID"))                       
                    threadHistory.Join()
                Next

    Public Sub GetRowHistory(ByVal ID As String)
            '1 min code from web srvice
    End Sub
```

If i have 10 Id's , how can i know whether all 10 threads were completed or not.

Comment: what do you mean by id's` `ManagedThreadId`?

Comment: I guess he's talking about 10 different database IDs

Comment: Its unique ID's for ex:1000 to 1010

Comment: ah, then you can go for @Luis solution which looks ideal.

Comment: You should use asynchronous calls to web service instead of starting n number of threads. Show your code in `GetRowHistory`

Comment: In The Luis solution showing error,JoinAll() is not a memeber for List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting and joining the thread one after the other. That is, perhaps, not your intent. If you keep it that way ou create a single thread, wait for it to finish and only then proceed to the next element.

I'd try the following: for each thread add it to a list or array and after the For Each/Next Statement You can Join them all with the property, i guess, `JoinAll()`

```
Dim List( Of Thread) allThreads  = new List
Dim threadHistory As Thread = Nothing

                For Each dRow As DataRow In sqlDS.Tables(0).Rows
                    GetPropertyBidHistory(dRow("ID"))
                    threadHistory = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetRowHistory)
                    threadHistory.Name = "Row" + dRow("ID")    
                    allThreads.Add(threadHistory)
                    threadHistory.Start(dRow("ID"))                       

                Next
Thread.JoinAll(allThreads) 'Blocks until all the threads finish
```

Comment: How can we add JoinAll for List

Comment: I changed my call of JoinAll. I do not have VS right now so i am doing by heart, sorry

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I changed it  For Each t As Thread In allThreads
                    t.Join()
                Next